# Android in-app purchase for alpha test mode

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I uploaded APK file to Alpha/Beta test mode. and published it.
I activated my in-app purchase id.
I created some tester emails.

But I can test it. After pressing "buy", app shows a alert 'The item that you were attempting to purchase could not be found'.

Please help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check your in app item ID (SKU), this must be the same as in your developer console. Remove any spaces at the beginning and end.